# Chemical bond of adsorbed atoms

Tags: bond, adsorption

When oxygen is adsorbed on iron metallic surface, does it create $\ce{Fe-O}$ bonds like the one in iron oxide? Can it be considered as a monolayer of iron oxide on the surface?

If not, how is the atomic bond of adsorbed oxygen and iron? How much is it strong? and what is its difference with normal chemical bond in iron oxide molecule?